# Could you please explain clustering in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server-2012, load-balancing

I'm new to clustering concepts. I would like to know more parallel processing with multiple DB nodes to have load balancing for the incoming requests. Our main goal is to achieve performance and lot of queries held in queue that come from for BI applications.

Is there any built in mechanism in SQL server to redirect requests to secondary node? We have huge volume of queries that runs on specific day and we need to distribute to secondary node.

We have SQL server 2012 in place and one database server up and running.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes, I'm interested in AG. we have a data warehouse built in SQL Server . Is there way to increase processing capacity to handle  more requests by Database server?  As I mentioned, we are thinking to scale out to additional server and set up some load balancing mechanism. Suggest some ideas.